# Watin : How to iterate over table rows when there is nothing to identify them

Tags: watin

I have tried different solutions to get the table node which I can identify as next sibling to the text node in the existing dom.

I used the following code, but the nextsibling is always null.

```
  var element = browser.Element(Find.ByText(t => t.Contains("Individual Notices")));

                        if (element != null)
                        {
                           var table = element.NextSibling as Table;
                        }
```

Would appreciate the help if any one can guide me how to iterate through the rows which are there in the table next to the node "Individual Notices"

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble as the `Contains` ends up not finding the element you want.  Put `Console.WriteLine("START" + element.Text+ "END");` in there right after the variable declaration/assignment, and I bet you'll see a whole lot of text output besides "Individual Notices".

If the Dom element you need ONLY has the text "Individual Notices" text, simply remove the lambda call and have `Find.ByText("Individual Notices")` and then `table` will have your table.

If this is not an option as the text isn't a known value, you might be able to search on a specific element type (eg: Div) so that parent nodes aren't being returned as the lambda contains result.

**Edit**:

Sometimes searching for an individual element by text is problematic due to browser oddities.  At times text values shown to the user don't necessarily equal the text values seen by the DOM due to whitespaces being added or removed.  Basically you might think you have "Individual Notices" but WatiN might see "Individual Notices "  <- See the space at the end.  The way I run not being able to find a particular element after easy/obvious methods are exhausted is to just iterate through the elements in WatiN code by searching for what I *think* should find it and then flashing the elements found and/or writing to the console.  If not found, widen the search.  Repeat as needed.

Comment: OCary@ Thanks for your reply, appreciate your help but when i search using var element = browser.Element(Find.ByText("Individual Notices")); I dont get any node back. I did not get what else I can do.

Comment: OCary@ Thanks for the reply, yes, you are correct. There is a space. I shall try to iterate add find the table. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it. Cheers mate!